# Inheritance supported by objective c

Tags: ios, inheritance

Hi I am a newbie in objective c.I am going through the concepts of inheritance in objective c.On reading a tutorial on tutorials point.I found that objective C supports multilevel inheritance.But whatever I have implemented now it appears that objective c supports Hierarchical inheritance also.As we can see in the following code:

```
@interface Shape : NSObject

{
    CGFloat area;
}
@end

@interface Square : Shape
{
    CGFloat length;
}
@end

@interface Rectangle : Shape
{
    CGFloat length;
    CGFloat breadth;
}
 @end
```

In such situation,Please help me to understand now the type of inheritances supported by objective c

Comment: This is not a multilevel inheritance.

Comment: Yes, this is not multilevel but hierarchical inheritance.

Comment: yes, and i use this all the time, anyone who codes on massive code bases uses this same thing to subclass subclasses to subclass, multiple level subclassing, they all inherit from NSObject anyway, everything in iOS is an NSObject at it's core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multi-level inheritance is where you have several generations of classes:

```
@interface Shape : NSObject
{
    CGFloat area;
}
@end

@interface Rectangle : Shape
{
    CGFloat length;
    CGFloat breadth;
}
@end

@interface Square : Rectangle
{
}
@end
```

In the example above, the base class is shape. A `Rectangle` is a type of `Shape`, and a `Square` is a type of `Rectangle`. The `Rectangle`'s parent class is `Shape`. The `Square`'s parent class is `Rectangle`, and it's "grandparent" class is `Shape`. 
(Squares are a special type of rectangle). A square doesn't need any extra properties. In fact it needs less properties than a rectangle.)

Hierarchical inheritance is where a parent class has more than one child class. For example, a shape class might have child classes of Rectangle, Circle, and Triangle.

Objective-C supports both types of inheritance.

`Multiple` inheritance is a different thing. That's where a class can inherit traits from multiple parents. Objective-C does not support multiple inheritance. Neither does Swift or Java for that matter.

(BTW the terms multi-level inheritance and hierarchical inheritance are not widely used in the industry. I had to look them up on Wikipedia in order to understand the distinction. I can't think of an object-oriented language that does not support both multi-level inheritance and hierarchical inheritance.)

Answer (score 1):

Objective c doesn't support multiple inheritance. You can refer this link [Objective C programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/DefiningClasses/DefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH3-SW5)

Though you can mimic the functionality of multiple inheritance using protocols but there is no official support for multiple inheritance in objective c.